# httpWebRequest to Httpclient refactoring problem

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

Can't configure out how to switch from Httpwebrequest to Httpclient. Hope someone can help me. I'm trying to refactorig my net4 code to net6 and I can't deal with bytes, and not sure how to right deal with HttpClient.
Thank you a lot for any help.

Here's the old code

```
        public static string Request(string url, string method, string encoding, string[] header, string reqData,
            bool isReRequest, bool isDebug)
        {
            var getString = "";

            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CheckValidationResult;
                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
                httpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
                httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                //set some reasonable limits on resources
                httpWebRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
                httpWebRequest.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4;
                httpWebRequest.Method = method;
                //15 seconds timeout
                httpWebRequest.Timeout = 15000;

                //Set the http header, because some do not allow direct add, so one by one to find out can not add
                if (header != null && header.Length > 0)
                    foreach (var item in header)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Trim()) || item.Contains(":"))
                        {
                            var split = Regex.Split(item, ": ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[0];
                            switch (split.ToLower())
                            {
                                case "accept":
                                    httpWebRequest.Accept = Regex.Split(item, ": ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[1];
                                    break;
                                case "content-length":
                                    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = reqData.Length;
                                    break;
                                case "content-type":
                                    httpWebRequest.ContentType = Regex.Split(item, ": ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[1];
                                    break;
                                case "expect":
                                    httpWebRequest.Expect = Regex.Split(item, ": ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[1];
                                    break;
                                case "if-modified-since":
                                    httpWebRequest.IfModifiedSince =
                                        Convert.ToDateTime(Regex.Split(item, ": ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[1]);
                                    break;
                                case "referer":
                                    httpWebRequest.Referer = Regex.Split(item, ": ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[1];
                                    break;
                                case "transfer-encoding":
                                    httpWebRequest.TransferEncoding =
                                        Regex.Split(item, ": ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[1];
                                    break;
                                case "user-agent":
                                    httpWebRequest.UserAgent = Regex.Split(item, ": ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[1];
                                    break;
                                case "host":
                                    httpWebRequest.Host = Regex.Split(item, ": ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[1];
                                    break;
                                case "connection":
                                    //Discard the connection, set the error
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(item);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                if (method == "POST")
                    using (var dataStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        var reqDataByte = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding).GetBytes(reqData);
                        dataStream.Write(reqDataByte, 0, reqDataByte.Length);
                    }

                using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    var responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

                    if (responseStream != null)
                        using (var streamReader =
                            new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding)))
                        {
                            getString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) return getString;
                Stream data = null;
                try
                {
                    data = (ex.Response as HttpWebResponse)?.GetResponseStream();
                    if (data != null)
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
                        {
                            getString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                }
                catch (WebException e)
                {
                    if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
                        Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    else throw;
                }

                if (data != null && data != Stream.Null) data.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                getString = "Exception Request";
                if (!isReRequest)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    getString = Request(url, method, encoding, header, reqData, true, isDebug);
                }

                if (isDebug) getString = "Exception Request:" + ex.Message;
            }

            return getString;
        }
```

Here is my wrong refactoring.
Thank you to help me.

```
        public static string Request(string url, string method, string encoding, string[] header, string reqData,
            bool isReRequest, bool isDebug)
        {
            var getString = "";

            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CheckValidationResult;
                var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
                {
                    handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                    handler.MaxAutomaticRedirections = 4;
                    handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip |
                                                     DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
                }

                var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
                httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(method), url));
                httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);

                if (header is {Length: > 0})
                    foreach (var item in header)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Trim()) || item.Contains(':'))
                        {
                            var split = Regex.Split(item, ": ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[0];
                            switch (split.ToLower())
                            {
                                case "accept":
                                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(Regex.Split(item, ": ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[1]));

                                    break;
                                case "content-length":
                                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(@"Content-Length", reqData.Length.ToString());
                                    break;
                                case "content-type":
                                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(@"Content-Type", Regex.Split(item, ": ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[1]);
                                    break;
                                case "expect":
                                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Expect.Add(new NameValueWithParametersHeaderValue(Regex.Split(item, ": ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[1]));
                                    break;
                                case "if-modified-since":
                                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.IfModifiedSince =
                                        Convert.ToDateTime(Regex.Split(item, ": ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[1]);
                                    break;
                                case "referer":
                                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = new Uri(Regex.Split(item, ": ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[1]);
                                    break;
                                case "transfer-encoding":
                                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TransferEncoding.Add(new TransferCodingHeaderValue(Regex.Split(item, ": ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[1]));
                                    break;
                                case "user-agent":
                                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue(Regex.Split(item, ": ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[1]));
                                    break;
                                case "host":
                                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = Regex.Split(item, ": ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)[1];
                                    break;
                                case "connection":
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(item, url);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                if (method == "POST")
                {
                    using var dataStream = httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url); 
                    var reqDataByte = Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding).GetBytes(reqData);
                    dataStream.Result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(reqDataByte, 0, reqDataByte.Length);
                }

                using var response = httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                var responseStream = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStream();

                {
                    {
                        using var streamReader =
                            new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(encoding));
                        getString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) return getString;
                Stream data = null;
                try
                {
                    data = (ex.Response as HttpWebResponse)?.GetResponseStream();
                    if (data != null)
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
                        {
                            getString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                }
                catch (WebException e)
                {
                    if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
                        Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    else throw;
                }

                if (data != null && data != Stream.Null) data.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                getString = "Exception Request";
                if (!isReRequest)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    getString = Request(url, method, encoding, header, reqData, true, isDebug);
                }

                if (isDebug) getString = "Exception Request:" + ex.Message;
            }

            return getString;
```

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear what exactly is not working. 1) HttpClient can handle strings directly 2) No need to specify the HttpClientHandler your way, as it is exactly matching the default handler used by the HttpClient 3) you MUST await asnyc methods like SendAsync. Otherwise you get unpredictable behavior. 4) Use string.Split instead of Regex for better performance. At least split the string once and store the left and right hand value of the separartor. 5) Timeout of 15s might be to short

Comment: 6) It does not make sense to handle a response STREAM in your context - simply call GetStringAsync() 7) If you handle streams you must dispose them too - use the `using` statement. 8) Don't use Thread.Sleep in an async contex! Use Thread.Delay instead (and don't forget to await it!) 9) Don't call all sorts of Get... members consecutively. Each call dispatches a new request. Request the response once

Comment: 10) SendAsync already sends and returns a response message - which you discard in your code. 11) If you need to POST a request use the PostAsync method. 12) Get... is actually a GET request - fyi

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in 8): it must be Task.Delay, of course. 8) Don't use Thread.Sleep in an async contex! Use Task.Delay instead (and don't forget to await it!)

Comment: Hello @BionicCode, what is the perfect way to handle the WebException for HttpClient? Is it HttpRequestException that should be used here?

Comment: @yuv Hello. It depends on the scenarios you want to recover from. In the example's case it's the send context. `HttpRequestException` allows to recover from network related errors. `InvalidOperationException` is raised when you send the same message instance twice. `TaskCanceledException` when you want to provide cancellation support.

Comment: @yuv Also note that the example's code is unnecessarily complex.  For simple HTTP the `HttpClient` is properly pre-configered by default. And more important, API methods like ´SendAsync´ and ´Getasync´ return a request/response object that is disposable. Don't forget to dispose it, preferably using the `using` expression or statement. The `HttpClient` is also disposable. Although `HttpClient` is designed to be kept alive for the lifetime of the application you want to consider to dispose it beforehand. to free allocated resources if you don't expect to handle more HTTP traffic.